# find out when was my memory card removed from Samsung J5

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, logging

My memory card of my work phone got stolen and i want to find out when was it stolen.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Android SDK. Connect your device (with USB-Debugging enabled) and, at a Terminal enter the following:

```
$ adb logcat -d > logcat.txt
```

The `-d` option tells adb to copy the entire File Log from the Android System. Because you seem to know how UNIX Systems work, I won't explain the rest of the command.
A second option (if you are rooted, that is) is to install a Terminal Emulator on your Android device. Open the Terminal Emulator and enter the command:

```
$ logcat -d > /sdcard/my-log-file.txt
```

This will do the same as above (except you don't need a computer, and the file saves on your device`/SDcard`. Feel free to change the " `/sdcard/my-log-file.txt` " part to anything you like, but I strongly recommend you save it to either your external or internal storage - so in short: Save it to a location you can accsess without `#` (superuser) permission!

Answer courtesy of @Ankush

Comment: That only helps if it was removed quite recently, and the device not rebooted since: reboot would flush the log, and being a ring buffer, newer entries overwrite olders after a while. Further: what to look for in the log file to identify the removal of the card? Your post just describes how to dump the log.